# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? issue in case of Https API hit though Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I suspect this is happening when the HttpClient is unable to receive the SSL certificate while performing the initial handshake. ST of the exception is mentioned below:

```
..
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
```

A weird thing is that the cURL command is working fine and I'm able to get the response from the HTTPs server. The cURL headers won't help but still attaching them:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 248188
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Also, the environment is configured up under a proxy server but this endpoint has been added as an exception, so proxy isn't involved here.
The **SSL certificate** has already been imported and the server is actually **HTTPS**. Please help me with the possible root causes.

Comment: It is more likely that you reach and endpoint which is not properly configured for HTTPS or that you use the wrong URL or configuration. Unfortunately the output from curl does not help much since it does not show that any HTTPS is actually involved here. It does show though that curl is using a proxy - which according to your question should not be the case. Maybe your exception does not work and your application is hitting the proxy with a TLS handshake - which is not what is expected by the proxy and which then returns with a plain HTTP error message. This would explain the error.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The cURL headers also include the link tag: (Link: <https://completeurl) which suggests the current link being https. Also, I'm able to get the data in response from this API. Isn't it adequate to assume that the endpoint is properly configured for Https.

Comment: Ahh! Can you please help me with the header referring to the proxy being used here :)

Comment: I can only help based on the information I see in your question and from these it is not clear what curl is really doing. *"Can you please help me with the header referring to the proxy being used here :)"* - I have no idea what you mean with that. Whatever this *"header referring to the proxy"* is.

Comment: You mentioned above 'It does show though that curl is using a proxy'. I thought you suspected this from the header information. I'm sure that the cURL command is executed without setting any proxy.

Comment: The first line "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established" is the response to a proxy CONNECT request. curl is definitely using a proxy here.